# can we push folder named node_modules to npm registry

Tags: npm

I want to push the pacakage to npm with existing node_modules.But when I try to publish the package node_modules folder will not be published. Can anybody please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The `node_modules` folder of your package will never be pushed. The node_modules folder is used to store the files of installed dependencies. You `package.json` file defines which modules in which versions should be installed. While installing your package via `npm install ...` the package.json will be parsed and any dependencies will be fetched and installed too, inside a newly created `node_modules` folder.

TLDR: The contents of the `node_modules` folder are "described" in your `package.json`, npm can create it on installation instead of copying thousands of files.

This is used to reduce duplications and offer looser bindings between modules.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explaination

Comment: If you found this answer helpful you may accept it too.